# Accepting method parameters in Java

Tags: java, methods

my problem is confusing me because I have done this before and it worked in previous programs but this particular program will not work. I just need to use the method typeInput and popularityNumber with the 2 variables I passed to them but I cannot call them in my main method without error. Either a ")" or ";" expected occurs, and it looks to me like there are parenthesis and semi colons where needed. I'm sure it's a quick fix and would appreciate learning how to fix it. Thank you!

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        nameInput();
         typeInput(Scanner keyboard, CartoonStar star);
       popularityNumber();


    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     */
    public static void nameInput() {

        System.out.println("What is the name of the cartoon character : ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        CartoonStar star = new CartoonStar();
        String name = keyboard.next();
        star.setName(name);

    }

    public static void typeInput(Scanner keyboard, CartoonStar star){
        System.out.println("What is the cartoon character type: 1 = FOX,2 = CHICKEN,3 = RABBIT,4 = MOUSE,5 = DOG,\n"
                + "6 = CAT,7 = BIRD,8 = FISH,9 = DUCK,10 = RAT");

        switch (keyboard.nextInt())
                {case 1 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.FOX);
                    break;

                case 2 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.CHICKEN);
                    break;
                case 3 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.RABBIT);
                    break;
                case 4 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.MOUSE);
                    break;
                case 5 : 
                    star.setType(CartoonType.DOG);
                    break;
                case 6 : 
                    star.setType(CartoonType.CAT);
                    break;
                case 7 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.BIRD);
                    break;
                case 8 :
                    star.setType(CartoonType.FISH);
                    break;
                case 9 :
                    star.setType (CartoonType.DUCK);
                    break;
                case 10 : 
                    star.setType(CartoonType.RAT);
                    break;
        }
    }


        public static void popularityNumber(Scanner keyboard, CartoonStar star){
        System.out.println("What is the cartoon popularity number?");
        int popularity = keyboard.nextInt();
        star.setPopularityIndex(popularity);
        System.out.println(star.getName() + star.getType() + star.getPopularityIndex());
    }
}







CartoonStar class (just in case you want it): 




public class CartoonStar {


  private String name;   
  private CartoonStar.CartoonType type;  
  enum CartoonType {
      FOX(1),CHICKEN(2),RABBIT(3),MOUSE(4),DOG(5),CAT(6),BIRD(7),FISH(8),DUCK(9),RAT(10);

  private final int animalType;
  private static Map <Integer, CartoonType> map = new HashMap <Integer, CartoonType>();
  private CartoonType(int animalType){

  this.animalType=animalType;
  }

  public int getAnimlType(){
  return animalType;}


  }//enum types
  private int popularityIndex;  //1 to 10 10 being the most popular

  public CartoonStar() {
  }//end no argument construtor

  public CartoonStar(String name,CartoonStar.CartoonType type, int popularityIndex) {
    setName(name);
    setType(type);
    setPopularityIndex(popularityIndex);
  }//end full constructor

  //getters and setters
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }      
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setType(CartoonStar.CartoonType type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
  public CartoonStar.CartoonType getType() {
    return type;
  }
  public void setPopularityIndex(int popularityIndex){
    this.popularityIndex = popularityIndex;
  }
  public int getPopularityIndex(){
    return popularityIndex;
  }  

}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: It was saying : " ')' expected. ';" expected."  Buhakes explanation answered my question well enough to make my program functional, however if you want to take a swing at it feel free.

Comment: The full error message? Does it give a line number?

Comment: it would have been lines 24 and 25, it did not reference a particular line that I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main method, you call your method as follows:

```
typeInput(Scanner keyboard, CartoonStar star);
```

The `typeInput` method expects a **declared** `keyboard` and **declared** `star`. You have called it incorrectly.

Your best option will be as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
    nameInput();
    popularityNumber();
}

public static void nameInput() {

    System.out.println("What is the name of the cartoon character : ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    CartoonStar star = new CartoonStar();
    String name = keyboard.next();
    star.setName(name);

    typeInput(keyboard, star);
}
```

I added `typeInput()` in your `nameInput()` method and removed it from the `main()` method.

Comment: That is what I thought and I tried a few times, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Ah I see. Is either process particularly more efficient than the other? Or is doing it from the main just not possible?

Comment: I was showing that calling a method that requires method variables, one needs to pass a `declared` value or a `null`. See the way of how I called the method as to how you did previously.